# Create RVM installation on single user that is in sudo group

Tags: ruby, rubygems, rvm, bundler

I am on the sudo group in linux. I believe the rvm package I am working with lives in a root directory. Currently, if I do a `bundle`, it tries to install the gems in the rvm package living in the root directory, and hence I get permission errors. If I try doing `sudo bundle`, I somehow seem to switch to an older version of ruby, and bundle fails.

I would like to:

- get sudo to use the newer version of ruby
- have a user specific rvm folder

How can I achieve this?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to start from scratch you can use:

```
rvm implode
sudo rvm implode
```

> implode    - (seppuku) removes the rvm installation completely.
>                  This means everything in $rvm_path (~/.rvm || /usr/local/rvm).
>                  This does not touch your profiles. However, this means that you
>                  must manually clean up your profiles and remove the lines which s